# GPG Details of Anatomy

Tags: pgp

What is the "created" field below? How can you translate that into an actual date?

[image]

Source: https://davesteele.github.io/gpg/2014/09/20/anatomy-of-a-gpg-key/

Comment: [Don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).

Answer (score 1):

It is a date that the creator of the signature chose to sign, usually representing the time at which the signature was created, in [POSIX time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), namely the approximate number of SI seconds that have elapsed on Earth's surface since January 1, 1972 at 00:00 in UTC, plus 63072000, minus the number of those that were labeled as leap seconds in UTC.

The Wikipedia article currently (2018-03-02) names January 1, 1970 at 00:00 in UTC as the reference point, but that must be interpreted as *proleptic* UTC because modern UTC, or just ‘UTC’ today, did not begin until 1972.  The [OpenPGP standard, RFC 4880, §3.5 ‘Time fields’](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-3.5) makes the same mistake, and does not mention leap seconds, but basically all implementations agree to subtract the number of seconds that were labeled as leap seconds.

You can print a UTC representation of the same date and time given its POSIX time representation using the GNU coreutils date(1) utility as follows:

```
$ date -u --date=@1281838967
Sun Aug 15 02:22:47 UTC 2010
```